# SOAP Extension Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, web-config

Regarding SOAP Extension implementation
I am create one class TraceException in which implement SoapExtension interface according to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx.

```
and also configure web.config as below:

<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <webServices>
     <soapExtensionTypes>
      <add type="Logger.LoggerExtension,logger"
           priority="1"
           group="0" />
     </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
 </system.web>
</configuration>

but till i am not able to create log file for SOAP Request and Response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to implement in this way.

Create TraceExtension class according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx.

Craete proxy class of webservice using following collmands wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs http://hostServer/WebserviceRoot/WebServiceName.asmx?WSDL

Put TraceExtension like this in webservice method for which method you want to create log file for soap request and response

[TraceExtension, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2017/04/swsim/swsimv62/AuthenticateUser", RequestNamespace = "http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2017/04/swsim/swsimv62", ResponseNamespace = "http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2017/04/swsim/swsimv62", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]

**Access web-service method by create object of Proxy class**